# Wrong wording on date based hat descriptions

Tags: bug, winter-bash, dates

The [Bûche de Noël](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/b%C3%BBche-de-no%C3%ABl) hat description says

> Ask, answer, or vote ±12h from Dec 25, 0:00 UTC

and [Where in the World](https://winterbash2020.stackexchange.com/where-in-the-world-sun) is similarly worded.

However, I already got the hat while it's only 10:55 UTC as I'm writing this; more than 12 hours before December 25th midnight. I think this is because the window actually starts [14 hours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC%2B14:00) before UTC midnight, not twelve. Furthermore, this would suggest the hat is only available until December 25th, 12:00 UTC, so only 24 hours, which is not correct (I suppose): date-based hats have always been available until *the next day* 12:00 UTC. Can the wording be changed to something like

> Ask, answer, or vote when it is December 25th somewhere on Earth

Comment: should also do this for the "where in the world" ones as well

Comment: You can blame Kiritimati UTC+14 (although I would be surprised if there are any SE users living there). Appropriately enough it is also known as Christmas Island.